# Creating AsyncTask with constructors gives me errors

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to create an AsyncTask to access my Room database. Here is the class:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    private Activity activity;
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    private String userEmail;
    public MyTask(Activity activity ,int userId, String userName, String userEmail) {
        this.activity= activity;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

All goes well, i can initialize the class in my fragment from where I access the DB (tried it without a constructor). But if I try to initialize it with constructors (as you can see above) it doesn't want to compile

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(getActivity(),1,"Bob","someEmail").execute();
```

It gives me this error:
[image]

I assume this is real simple. Alas, google didn't help me on this one and I already have a flimsy understanding of AsyncTask. I just don't understand how adding a constructor changes the type of the instance (from MyTask to AsyncTask).

Comment: Remove `.execute()` and do something like `myTask.execute()`

Comment: MyTask myTask = new MyTask (..) **.execute();** is a problem. `.execute` does not return `MyTask `. Do `MyTask myTask = new MyTask (..);myTask .execute(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `execute()` after instantiating your MyTask (`execute()` returns AsyncTask as you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute(Params...))) .

So change this:

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(getActivity(),1,"Bob","someEmail").execute();
```

to this:

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(getActivity(),1,"Bob","someEmail");
myTask.execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

//AsyncTask do these changes

```
private Context context;

public MyTask(Context context ,int userId, String userName, String userEmail) {
    this.context= context;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
}
```

//here the classname can be ur activityname

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask(ClassName.this,1,"Bob","someEmail").execute();
```

always pass as arguments for asynctask not in constructor